# Do I need to build a node.js app in order to use trigger.io?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, trigger.io

I'm a Rails noob very interested in experimenting with mobile app development using trigger.io.

I see the 'build for web' feature creates a node.js app, and I'm curious to learn whether that means my backend app must be node, and not Rails. I have no node experience and would like to leverage the Rails skills I have, if I can.

Thanks for any info/pointers to resources that help me better understand how to plan my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Trigger.io doesn't require you to write any back-end code at all, and if you wish to have server-side logic, you can use Rails or any framework you like.

We provide a node.js proxy as part of our 'build to web' feature so if you wanted to use that feature you would need to host node.js somewhere as well as having your Rails back-end. We have a tight integration with Heroku, so it is as simple as running 'forge package web' to deploy.